# Mostrar y ocultar elementos con tiempo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Necesito mostrar y ocultar primero 3 indicadores, y despues mostrar y ocultar los otros 3, tengo el código de esta manera, me muestra y oculta los primeros 3, los otros 3 no, pensé que de esta manera funcionaria:

```html
   
                    <div id="contenido">
                    <div id="content-text1"></div>
                    <div id="content-text2"></div>
                    <div id="content-text3"></div>
                    
                    <div id="contenido2" style="display:none">
                    <div id="content-text4"></div>
                    <div id="content-text5"></div>
                    <div id="content-text6"></div>
                    
                   
                
    
                <script>
                $(function(){
                $.ajax({url: "https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators", 
                success: function(result){
                $("#content-text1").html(result);
                $("#content-text1").html($(".item-row[data-item='UVR'] .item-value > span ").text());
                $("#content-text2").html(result);
                $("#content-text2").html($(".item-row[data-item='TRM'] .item-value > span ").text());
                $("#content-text3").html(result);
                $("#content-text3").html($(".item-row[data-item='EURCOP'] .item-value > span ").text());
                $("#content-text4").html(result);
                $("#content-text4").html($(".item-row[data-item='DTF'] .item-value > span ").text());
                $("#content-text5").html(result);
                $("#content-text5").html($(".item-row[data-item='OILVAL'] .item-value > span ").text());
                $("#content-text6").html(result);
                $("#content-text6").html($(".item-row[data-item='COFFEE'] .item-value > span ").text());
                }});
                });
        </script>
  
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Ejecutamos método que oculta las cajas
        OcultarContenedores1();
      
        //Cada 6 segundos ejecutamos la función que reinicializa los contenedorees
        setInterval(function() {
          OcultarContenedores2();
        }, 12000);
      
      });
      
      //Método que oculta el primer contenedor para mostrar el otro
      function OcultarContenedores1() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#contenido").hide(6000);
        }, 3000);
      
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#contenido2").show(12000);
        }, 3000);
      }
      //Método que reinicializa los contenedores
      function OcultarContenedores2() {
        $('#contenido').show(6000);
        $('#contenido2').hide(12000);
      }

      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estuve leyendo el código y no se bien realmente que quieres lograr, por que ocultas los 2 contenedores principales, por eso al ejecutar el código no muestra nada

Comment: Como te digo, tengo 6 indicadores económicos, necesito que salgan 3 y se oculten, y después salgan los otros 3 y se oculten, lo que trataba de hacer era duplicar el código y hacerlo con los otros 3 me hago entender? @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila, en estos momentos me muestra los primeros 3

Comment: sabes como hacerlo?En verdad necesito ayuda. @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila

Comment: Con lo que pusiste en la pregunta no es fácil ayudarte enserio

Comment: Mira la imagen que si me salen los primeros 3 y después se ocultan, pero no me salen los otros 3. @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila, lo que pretendo lograr es que primero salgan 3 y se oculten, salgan los otros 3 y se oculten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Que tal, como te va, amigo, espero esto te de ideas o te ayude a solucionar tu problema.**

*"Edité el código, quizá con este nuevo método tengas más libertad de manipular los tiempos de salida y ocultación de los contenedores, y de esta manera, el método está más optimizado."*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function hideShowContainers() {
    //Validamos si contenedor2 tiene la clase 'jsHideContainer'  
    if ($('#contenido2').hasClass('jsHideContainer')) {
      //Eliminamos la clase 'jsHideContainer' para validar la parte negativa del condicional
      $('#contenido2').removeClass('jsHideContainer');
      //Ocultamos el contenedor1 mientras pasan 3 segundos  
      $('#contenido').hide(3000);
      //Mostramos el contenedor2 mientras pasan 3 segundos
      $('#contenido2').show(3000);
    } else {
      //Ocultamos el contenedor2 mientras pasan 3 segundos
      $('#contenido2').hide(3000);
      //Mostramos el contenedor1 mientras pasan 3 segundos
      $('#contenido').show(3000);
      //Finalmente adicionamos la clase jsHideContainer para validar la parte positiva del condicional
      $('#contenido2').addClass('jsHideContainer');
    }
  }

  //Ejecutamos la función para que evalue los condicionales cada 5 segundos
  setInterval(hideShowContainers, 5000);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="contenido" style="background:#f4f3f2;">
    <div id="content-text">Contenido 1</div>
    <div id="content-text2">Contenido 2</div>
    <div id="content-text3">Contenido 3</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="contenido2" class="jsHideContainer" style="background:#f1eee3;display:none">
    <div id="content-text4">Contenido 4</div>
    <div id="content-text5">Contenido 5</div>
    <div id="content-text6">Contenido 6</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba, mil gracias.

Comment: De nada, me alegra haber podido ayudarte a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Amigo, mira, me están saliendo los dos al tiempo.

Comment: Mmmm.. Vale, dime en que momento específicamente y miramos

Comment: Como puedo hacer para que el primer contenido salga mas o menos a los 6 segundos y se oculte a los 11? me hago entender y el segundo sale de los 12 segundos y se oculta a los 19? mira edité el código arriba.

Comment: Ok, Ya intentaste modificando el tiempo del setTimeOut en #contenido para 'ocultar' y en setInterVal para 'aparecer'?

Comment: Es que apenas carga la página ahí mismo aparece el valor

Comment: Ok, mira Lucas, ahora yo voy a salir, pero en este rato estuve pensado y creo que ya tengo una solición definitiva para tu problema, déjame yo ordeno algunas ideas sueltas y mañana continuamos y te explico mejor, vale?

Comment: Si claro vale, gracias.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91068/discussion-between-lucas-suarez-and-fernando-chamorro).

Comment: Lucas, mira el nuevo codigo, lo edité y lo simplifiqué más, ahora si puedes manipular los tiempos de mejor forma.

Answer (score 3):

puedes hacerlo asi:

**Javascript puro:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
function mostrar(el, time,infi=false) {
    let p = document.querySelectorAll(el);
    let i = 0;
    // ejecutamos un intervalo de tiempo para los elementos
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        // validamos que no sea el elemento 0 para aplicarle el none al anterior!
        if (i != 0)p[i - 1].style.display = "none";
        //validamos si es igual al lenght para finalizar el bucle
        if (i == p.length) {
              //retornamos i a 0
              i=0;
            // limpiamos el intervalor para que no se ejecute mas si no es infinito
             if(!infi) clearInterval(interval)
            // retornamos para finalizar la funcion
            return;
        }
        // aplicamos el display block
        p[i].style.display = "block";
        // aumentamos i en 1
        i++;
    }, time)
}

mostrar('main div[id^="contenido"]', 2000);
}
```

```css
main > div{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <main>
    <div id="contenido1">
        <div id="content-text">Contenido 1</div>
        <div id="content-text2">Contenido 2</div>
        <div id="content-text3">Contenido 3</div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido2">
        <div id="content-text4">Contenido 4</div>
        <div id="content-text5">Contenido 5</div>
        <div id="content-text6">Contenido 6</div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido3">
        <div id="content-text7">Contenido 7</div>
        <div id="content-text8">Contenido 8</div>
        <div id="content-text9">Contenido 9</div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenido4">
        <div id="content-text10">Contenido 10</div>
        <div id="content-text11">Contenido 11</div>
        <div id="content-text12">Contenido 12</div>
    </div>
</main>
```

**version jquery con infinito true:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function mostrar(el, time,infi=false) {
    let p = $(el);
    let i = 0;
    // ejecutamos un intervalo de tiempo para los elementos
    let interval = setInterval(() => {

        // validamos que no sea el elemento 0 para aplicarle el none al anterior!
        if (i != 0) $(p[i-1]).hide();
        //validamos si es igual al lenght para finalizar el bucle
        if (i == p.length) {
             //retornamos i a 0
              i=0;
            // limpiamos el intervalor para que no se ejecute mas si no es infinito
             if(!infi) clearInterval(interval)
        }
        // aplicamos el display block
        $(p[i]).show("slow");
        // aumentamos i en 1
        i++;
    }, time)
}
mostrar('main div[id^="contenido"]', 2000,true);
});
```

```css
  main > div{
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
        <div id="contenido1">
            <div id="content-text">Contenido 1</div>
            <div id="content-text2">Contenido 2</div>
            <div id="content-text3">Contenido 3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="contenido2">
            <div id="content-text4">Contenido 4</div>
            <div id="content-text5">Contenido 5</div>
            <div id="content-text6">Contenido 6</div>
        </div>
        <div id="contenido3">
            <div id="content-text7">Contenido 7</div>
            <div id="content-text8">Contenido 8</div>
            <div id="content-text9">Contenido 9</div>
        </div>
        <div id="contenido4">
            <div id="content-text10">Contenido 10</div>
            <div id="content-text11">Contenido 11</div>
            <div id="content-text12">Contenido 12</div>
        </div>
    </main>
```